# How to type and model telemetry from IOT Central data export, routed through Event Hub and consumed in TSI?

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-iot-central, azure-timeseries-insights

When using IOT Central data export to Event Hub, you have a message format which is:

```
{
"applicationId": "A-GUID",
"component": null,
"deviceId": "AN-ID",
"enqueuedTime": "2022-02-23T20:34:11.0400000Z",
"enrichments": {},
"messageProperties": {},
"messageSource": "telemetry",
"module": null,
"schema": "default@v1",
"telemetry": [
{
"label": "temp",
"value": "33"
},
{
"label": "watts",
"value": 2183
}
...
"templateId": "A-TEMPLATE-ID",
"ts": "2022-02-23T20:26:39.0000000Z",
"EventProcessedUtcTime": "2022-02-23T20:37:53.1779856Z",
"PartitionId": 0,
"EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2022-02-23T20:34:12.5810000Z"
}
```

**My question is how do you unpack the Telemetry property into something which TSI can see as Types?**

The Type seems to rely on a flatter naming structure, like `$event.telemety.watts`, and there is no way to query for `$event.telemetrty.label == "watts`.

My one thought is that I may need to transform this data before it gets to TSI by using an inbound event hub, then a function to flatten the schema and an outbound event hub which is what TSI reads from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There's a new (to me) Transform feature in IoT Central Data Export.

We used the following rule to transform the telemetry.

`telemetry: .telemetry | map({ (.name|tostring): .value }) | add`